# ImageMagick 6.5.4: Call to undefined method Imagick::readFromBlob()

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have got this error happening when trying to manipulate an image using ImageMagick and PHP. Here is the code:

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

// Variables
$x = (int) $_POST['x'];
$y = (int) $_POST['y'];

$width = (int) $_POST['width'];
$height = (int) $_POST['height'];

// Source
$pos = strpos($_POST['src'], 'base64,') + 7;
$contents = base64_decode(substr($_POST['src'], $pos));

// Mime types
$types = array(
    'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
    'png' => 'image/png',
    'gif' => 'image/gif'
);

// Data
$data = array(
    'mime' => substr($_POST['src'], 5, $pos - 13)
);

$data['ext'] = array_search($data['mime'], $types);

if (!$data['ext']) {
    $data['ext'] = 'png';
}

// Image
$image = new Imagick;

$image->readFromBlob($contents);

if ($data['ext'] == 'gif') {
    $frames = $image->coalesceImages();
} else {
    $frames = array($image);
}

foreach ($frames as $frame) {
    $image->resizeImage($width, $height, Imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 0);
    $image->cropImage($config['width'], $config['height'], $x, $y);
}

// Save
$path = $config['saveas'];

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $path = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', $value, $path);
}

$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../' . $path;

$image->writeImage($path, $data['ext'] == 'gif');

echo json_encode(true);
```

And here's the info from phpinfo:

- imagick module   enabled
- imagick module version   3.1.0RC2
- imagick classes  Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel,
  ImagickPixelIterator
- ImageMagick version  ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2012-05-07 Q16 OpenMP

When using F12 in chrome and going through the processing of a small image this is my error in it's entirety:

AJAX error AvatarChanger.js:354

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method Imagick::readFromBlob() in        <b>/home/solidarity/cog/avatar/php/done.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />
```

If anyone here can help or has any ideas, please share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `readFromBlob` method (just as error message says), check out documentation and there you can find [`readImageBlob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimageblob.php)

Comment: Brilliant! However I now get this: <b>Warning</b>:  Imagick::writeimage() expects at most 1 parameter, 2 given in <b>/home/solidarity/cog/avatar/php/done.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
true

Comment: Are you even trying to read and understand these error messages? What do you expect after passing second argument? It is not documented anywhere and does not affect how the file will be saved. Second parameter is needed in other method - `writeImages()` (note plural form). Please try doing some research next time.

Comment: Apologies for offending you... I will not ask for help again.

Comment: You are not offending anyone, just showing no effort to solve problem for your own. If you continue to ask such questions, your account can get suspended or people will simply stop answering your questions, since most of us are here to share knowledge and experience, not to be manual search assistants.